# Laravel 9 show post

Tags: php, laravel

I made a crud and I would like to display it on the home page but I have an error. I explain : in views i have folder posts in this folder posts i have files create edit index master and show .blade.php in all files which are in folder posts can see the posts but in home.blade.php don't see i have error Undefined variable $posts

home.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Dashboard') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        {{ session('status') }}
                    </div>
                    @endif

                    {{ __('You are logged in!') }}
                </div>

                @foreach ($posts as $post)
                // now you can access your $post variable here...
                <h1> Title: {{ $post->title }} </h1>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

PostController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $post = Post::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'description' => $request->description
        ]);

        if ($post) {
            return redirect()->route('posts.index');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Post $post)
    {
        return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Post $post)
    {
        return view('posts.edit', compact('post'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
    {
        $post['title'] = $request->title;
        $post['description'] = $request->description;
        $post->save();
        return redirect()->route('posts.index');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    
    public function destroy(Post $post)
    {
        $post->delete();
        return redirect()->route('posts.index');
    }
}
```

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;



/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth/login');
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');


Route::resource('posts', PostController::class);
```

The crud works very well and we see it very well on another page that I called show, but I would like us to see the posts on the home page too. But I have an error: Undefined variable $post  How can I solve this, the posts must be displayed on the home page too

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot see `$post` in your `home.blade.php` is because you are passing in `$posts` and you are referencing `$post` in your blade file. There's nothing wrong with this, but you need to ensure to loop over `$posts` so that you can assign each post to a `$post` variable.

Something like:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
     // now you can access your $post variable here...
     <h1> Title: {{ $post->title }} </h1>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I have added like you talk i have the same error

Comment: Can you update your original question with your new code?

Comment: I have edit code and i have explain structure of view

Comment: You are passing in `posts.index` view, but you have your code in the `home.blade.php` file. Was this a typo?

Comment: In view i have folder posts in post i have Create,edit,index,master and show.blade.php in all this pages all work good, but i want to show post in page /home too but i have this error undefined variable in /home page

Comment: So can you replace your return statement with this: `return view('home', compact('posts'));` (or wherever your home file is).

Comment: I need to add this ` return view('home', compact('posts')); ` in Postcontroller add it at the bottom of `return view('posts.index', compact('posts')); `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247106/discussion-between-taylor-and-xajetin).

Comment: ok i have writing

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve this question need to add

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('home', compact('posts'));
}
```

In Homecontroller

Answer (score 0):

You send `posts` to `posts.index` blade but you're trying to access it in `home.blade.php`.

Comment: I have resolve this i have writing but thanks =)